# Django reverse() behind API Gateway/Proxy

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Django REST API is deployed behind an API Gateway (Kong).
I want to `reserve()` some urls  in my `APIViews`.
I would like to ask for help to get the right url format.
Based on basepath of the API gateway.

**Communication flow:**
Client (requesting basepath) <-> Kong (forwarding to upstream) <-> Apache (Reverse Proxy) <-> Django

Kong defines a **basepath** and an **upstream** to forward client request to Django.
Kong includes `X_FORWARDED_HOST` and `X_FORWARDED_PATH` in the HTTP header.
X_FORWARDED_PATH contains the basepath of the gateway.
X_FORWARDED_HOST contains the gateway-url.

Gateway basepath is:
`/gateway-basepath`

Upstream path is:
`mydomain.com/py/api/v1`

Basically, without gateway, Django `reverse()` creates following url for **users** endpoint:
`mydomain.com/py/api/v1/users/`

With the API gateway, the Django creates follow path:
`apigatewayurl.com/gateway-basepath/py/api/v1/users/`
Django is considering **X_FORWARDED_HOST**, but not **X_FORWARDED_PATH**

**I need following result:**
`apigatewayurl.com/gateway-basepath/users`
Otherwise the Django url resolving is not usable within the api gateway.

I would appreciate any help.

**urls.py**

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

class APIRootView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({
            'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        })

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', APIRootView.as_view(), name="api_root"),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth import models as django_models

from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = django_models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["url", "username", "email", "is_staff"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to solve it.

Django Rest Framework calls `[build_absolute_uri()]` ([Link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/http/request.py#L201)) from `django.http` to build the absolute url.
The variable `location` contains the generated url paths.

Without changing the core library, I used **monkepatching** to solve it.
Be aware, that this is a **breaking change**.
If Django will be updated, you have to check this function.

**settings.py**

```py
import django.http
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlsplit

def build_absolute_uri(self, location=None):
    if location is None:
        location = "//%s" % self.get_full_path()
    else:
        # Coerce lazy locations.
        location = str(location)
    
    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    # I ADD HERE MY CUSTOMIZATION
    # MODIFYING `location`
    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    location = location.replace(self.META["REQUEST_URI"], self.META["X_FORWARDED_PATH"])

    bits = urlsplit(location)
    if not (bits.scheme and bits.netloc):
        if (
            bits.path.startswith("/")
            and not bits.scheme
            and not bits.netloc
            and "/./" not in bits.path
            and "/../" not in bits.path
        ):
            location = self._current_scheme_host + location.removeprefix("//")
        else:
            location = urljoin(self._current_scheme_host + self.path, location)
    return iri_to_uri(location)

# do monkeypatch and overwrite core functionality with own function  
django.http.request.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri = build_absolute_uri
```